# Using Addforce with Rotation change?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object, that I want to move forward, without using W (like [here in this video](https://youtu.be/Au8oX5pu5u4?list=PLPV2KyIb3jR53Jce9hP7G5xC4O9AgnOuL&t=342)) and, like the video I use AddForce to do it:

```
public float forwardForce = 200f;

private void FixedUpdate()
{
     rb.AddForce(forwardForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
}
```

But I want for the object to rotate to the left 90 degrees each time i hit 'A'/'Left' (and vice versa/to the right too), as well as having that force pushing it the way it's currently turned.

I'm new to coding so please any help is appreciated.

Comment: `rb.AddForce(transform.forward * forwardForce);` may work better.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, using Time.deltaTime in FixedUpdate gives unexpected results. Use Time.fixedDeltaTime instead of it. Then, this code would do what you want.

```
private void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)
    {
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, 90), Space.Self);
    }
    else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D)
    {
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, -90), Space.Self);
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
     rb.AddForce(transform.forward * forwardForce * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
```

but if you use this method to move your object, after turning it still moves on previous direction. Maybe you can fix it with this way.

```
private void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)
    {
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, 90), Space.Self);
        rb.velocity = rb.velocity.magnitude*transform.forward;
    }
    else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D)
    {
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, -90), Space.Self);
        rb.velocity = rb.velocity.magnitude*transform.forward;
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
     rb.AddForce(transform.forward * forwardForce * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
```